# Making required EditText field in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am starting to make an app.  I currently have one EditText.  How do I make it required? When nothing is entered into the EditText! the message `Please Enter a username` should flash on the screen but it still goes to the next scene/activity.  How do I stop the submit if the length is 0.  I put return false into the public void but I get the following message `cannot return a value from a method with void result type`

```
    public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();

    //Trim whitespace
    message = message.trim();

    //Checks if the message has anything.
    if (message.length() == 0)
    {
        editText.setError("Please Enter a username!");
        //return false;
    }
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: cleaner way will be using if else
    if (message.length() == 0)
    {
        editText.setError("Please Enter a username!");
    }else{
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
string text=editText.getText().toString().trim();
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(text)){
            editText.setError("Please Enter a username!");
        }else {
            //do something
        }
```

Comment: it's a simple way I always use ,please try it and if it works with you accept my answer and if any if you have any inquiry I am available

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `return false;`, just write `return;` with no return type (because the method's return type is  `void`) and it should let you leave the method.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the function like the following.

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();

    //Trim whitespace
    message = message.trim();

    //Checks if the message has anything.
    if (message.length() == 0) {
        editText.setError("Please Enter a username!");
        return;
    }

    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `if` and `else` clause will achieve what you want.

```
//Checks if the message has anything.
if (message.length() == 0)
{
    editText.setError("Please Enter a username!");
    //return false;
} else {
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
if (!emptyEdittext(editText, "Please Enter a username!")) 
{
  intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
  startActivity(intent);
}}
```

2.Call below method for validation

```
public boolean emptyEdittext(EditText editText, String msg)
{
    /*check edittext length*/
    if(editText.getText().toString().length()==0)
    {
        Toast.makeText(activity, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the popup suggestion.  But what is `activity` I am new to android and java.  My guess is activity is name of the application?  I used `this` or `getApplicationContext()` and that worked.  But what is the name of my `activity`.  Would it be the name of my main class?

Comment: Use your activity name in which you use the above code like MainActivity.this instead of activity.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that a `TextEdit.getText().toString()` doesn't give you a null value... It gives you an empty string, which is still a string. Try this. It is the way I do it.

```
public void sendMessage(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();

    //Trim whitespace
    message = message.trim();

    //Checks if the message has anything. This checks to see if 
      //it has an empty string rather than a null
    if (message.equals(""))
    {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please provide a 
               message!, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT").show();
    }else
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,message);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit Peter. This was only my 3d answer on Stack Overflow and I am still getting used to the best practices.